# Convert excel sheet to pdf in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need to generate an excel file in my flutter app and convert it to a pdf file
what i want is to
Export the Excel workbook as a PDF. An app like Excel can do it, but it has a special exporting form where the user has to specify if he wants to export only the currently displayed sheet, or the whole workbook.

Ideally I would also like my user to be able to view or preview the spreadsheet from my app. No need for him to be able to edit the spreadsheet at this time, just be able to read it.

Comment: Did you try with excel from pub?

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far

Comment: i have tried cfusion_flutter_datagrid_export package